# How to plot multiple figures as subplots and multiples columns of a dataframe in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I’ve been attempting to plot all my columns of my dataframe in subplots but it does not work.
is there a smart way to make it?

```
import padas as pd
import seaborn as sns
    df = pd.DataFrame({'TR':np.arange(1, 6).repeat(5), 'A': np.random.randint(1, 100,25), 'B':  np.random.randint(50, 100,25), 'C':  np.random.randint(50, 1000,25), 'D':  np.random.randint(5, 100,25), 'E':  np.random.randint(5, 100,25),
                   'F':  np.random.randint(5, 100,25), 'G':  np.random.randint(5, 100,25), 'H':  np.random.randint(5, 100,25), 'I':  np.random.randint(5, 100,25), 'J':  np.random.randint(5, 100,25) })
row = 2
col = 5
r = sorted(list(range(0, row))*5)
c = list(range(0, col))*2

fig, axes = plt.subplots(row, col, figsize=(20, 10))

for j, k,i in zip( r, c, df.columns):
    plt.figure()
    g = sns.boxenplot(x = 'TR', y = df[i], ax= axes[j, k], data=df)

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that you need to move `plt.show` out of the loop, and stop creating new figure instance with `plt.figure`.

Also,

1. it's easier to flattern `axes` and zip
2. it looks like you want to plot from columns 1, not column 0

All together:

```
row = 2
col = 5

fig, axes = plt.subplots(row, col, figsize=(20, 10))

# flattern `axes` with `.ravel()`    
# notice the `[1:]`
for ax,i in zip( axes.ravel(), df.columns[1:]):
    # remove this as well
    #  plt.figure()

    # you just need to pass y = i
    g = sns.boxenplot(x = 'TR', y = i, ax= ax, data=df)

# move `plt.show()` out of for loop:
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Update** probably a more *seaborn way* is to use `FacetGrid`:

```
fg = sns.FacetGrid(data=df.melt('TR'), 
                   col='variable', col_wrap=5, sharey=False)
fg.map(sns.boxenplot,'TR','value',order=df['TR'].unique)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @MARCOSSANTOS you're welcome. See the update for another solution. Also, if it works for you, consider upvote/accept the answer.